# How to connect with Storage account in Azure automation runbook

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-automation, azure-runbook

In Azure automation runbook I want to connect with storage account and get the context without the account key. I can connect with the storage account key but I don't want to connect with storage key.

FYI

```
$Context = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName "cordus6abfsuat001" -UseConnectedAccount
echo $Context
```

ERROR is **"Context cannot be null."**

I am expecting to connect with storage account with out the storage account key.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a **[system-assigned managed identity for you Azure Automation account](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/enable-managed-identity-for-automation)**
[image]

Then, in your storage account, you got to:

1. Access Control
2. Add Role Assignment
   [image]

There you can give the Role Contributor for your Automation Account Identity
[image]
[image]
[image]
Hoppe This helps!

Comment: I can't change anything, I only do have reader access on that SA.

Comment: If you require to connect without a storage account key. You must ask to the administrator of the SA that they give permission for the AA

Answer (score 0):

> I am expecting to connect with storage account with out the storage account key.

**You can alternatively use Connection string and get the context as below and I followed [Microsoft-Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.storage/new-azstoragecontext?view=azps-9.2.0):**

```
Connect-AzAccount

$Context = New-AzStorageContext -ConnectionString "XX"

Write-Host $Context
```

XX is the Connection string of Storage account.

[image]

**Output:**

[image]

**You can also get it with uisng SAS token as below:**

```
$Context = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName "rithvayamo" -SasToken "sp=r&st=2022i4n3vHCuHye6PzkDLUbXTnQT2jeNphU1j0%3D"

Write-Host $Context
```

[image]

**Output:**

[image]